# How can I do Array[i][j]?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

I have the following array, but I want to make `array[i][j]= {1,4,5,6,7,4,4,3,2,3},{3,4,6,9,6,4,3,2,2,3},{12,32,32,3,4,5,6,7,7,8}`

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:86],
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:87],
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:88],
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:-23],
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:-24],
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:-46],
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:13],nil];
```

How can do this with Xcode and

```
for (i=0; i<amountOfViewsHorizontally; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < amountOfViewsVertically; j++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d", array [i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are set on using NSArray, you will have to make an array of arrays.  This would look like:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:86],
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:87],
                         nil],
                     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:12],
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:57],
                         nil],
                     nil];
```

And then you can access them by the following, (NOT the [] syntax)

```
NSNumber *number = [[array objectAtIndex: i] objectAtIndex: j];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather unclear. For what it's worth, however, you can certainly use 2-dimensional C-style arrays if you want to; Objective-C is a superset of C.